# Using 2 dynamic routes on the same level with Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I have the following structure inside my Nuxt 3 application:

```
├── pages
│   └── [section]
|   |   |
│   │   ├── [slug].vue
│   │   └── [[page]].vue
...
```

The `[[page]]` route is used as a page for the whole list of products, whereas `[slug]` is used to show the exact product.

The `page` parameter is optional, because you don't need the page number if you are on the first page.

For the following urls the `[[page]].vue` should be shown:

```
/dresses
/dresses/1
/dresses/2
/dresses/3
...
```

And for the following urls the `[slug].vue` should be shown:

```
/dresses/1235-nice-dress-for-the-party
/dresses/6703-pink-dress-made-of-cotton
...
```

The slug consists of the product code and the name

How could I achieve this?

Now it works if I don't add the page number such as `/dresses/`. But for `/dresses/2` it shows the `[slug].vue` page.

Comment: I don't think you can archive that. How `vue-router` is supposed to understand if `2` is a `slug`or a `page`? If you really need this, you can have two components, `slug.vue` and `page.vue` and just one page, with a `script setup` where a function understands if the `param` is a number or a string. Based on that, in the `template` you show the `slug` component or the `page` component.

Comment: @learntheropes I tried to achieve this with route validation, but if the validation fails, it throws 404 instead of trying to find another matching route

Comment: 404 for which page exactly? You also need a new file `index.vue` inside the `[section]` folder, to match the first page that has not a page number. In that file, you put the same component of pages. If you can make a reproduction on https://stackblitz.com/ I can look at it.